# C# unity constructor injection with parameter builder

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have a class in which I am using Unity constructor injection.

```
Class A
{
    public A(B b, C c)
    {

    }
}
```

Class `C` is a model(POCO) which needs to be build and then again passed to class `B`.

I would like to know a best way to build model `C` and pass it to `B`. I don't want to do this building outside of class `A`.

Comment: If that's the case then you're going to have to fulfill `B` manually in the constructor because I'm assuming class `C` isn't a Singleton. This further means that `B` isn't going to be injectable into `A`.

Comment: I can think of making C as Singleton also, it's basically a reference data model class. So should I just build c in A and B will automatically get it when I mentioned [Dependency]  attribute to it's prop in  class B? Is this the right approach?

Comment: If `C` can be a Singleton then you can pull this off with DI because both `A` and `B` would get the same instance resolved via the container.

Comment: Okay! I also feel making C as Singleton is right approach in this case(usually I try to avoid them) since it's same instance shared by all different class instances, so why to have separate copy.  Thanks!!! Mike

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance!